# WP 8.1 create Multi column lixtbox

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8.1

i would like to ask you how to create listbox with 2 columns.  I have listbox with tiles and i want create 2 columns of tiles like this image.

XAML ListBox

```
 <ListBox ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TileListBoxItemStyle}" Margin="0,130.499,56.483,-61.008" Height="568.509" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" UseLayoutRounding="True" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="311.852" Background="#CC020202" Tapped="ListBox_Tapped">
        <ListBox.RenderTransform>
            <CompositeTransform SkewY="0.505" TranslateY="-0.825"/>
        </ListBox.RenderTransform>
        <!-- set its ItemsPanel to be a WrapPanel -->
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel >
            <ItemsPanelTemplate >
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBoxItem>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="Messages" />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">

                    <TextBlock Text="test" FontSize="22" Margin="4,0,0,8" />
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
        </ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem/>
        <ListBoxItem/>
        <ListBoxItem/>
        <ListBoxItem/>
        <ListBoxItem/>
        <ListBoxItem/>
        <ListBoxItem/>
        <ListBoxItem/>


    </ListBox>
```

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing for widows runtime then you can also use *ListView* with [WrapGrid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.wrapgrid). It can look for example like this:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="20">
                <Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <x:String>Item 1</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 2</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 3</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 4</x:String>
    <x:String>Item 5</x:String>
</ListView>
```

And the result:

[image: listandwrapgrid]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ItemsPanel of the ListBox to a *WrapPanel*.

Windows Runtime does not bring an own WrapPanel implementation, but fur example the [WinRT Xaml Toolkit](http://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4d568d4e4c6a#WinRTXamlToolkit/Controls/WrapPanel/WrapPanel.cs) has one.